# Build one jar per platform for multi-platform SWT application

Tags: java, ant, jar, swt, multiplatform

There are a couple of questions to this topic already, but none of them seem to work properly.

Here is a list of them:

- [Bulding an multi-platform SWT application using Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894483/bulding-an-multi-platform-swt-application-using-ant)
- [Build multi-platform executable for a SWT application (Eclipse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22303755/build-multi-platform-executable-for-a-swt-application-elipse)
- [Build multi-platform executable for a SWT application using maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285598/build-multi-platform-executable-for-a-swt-application-using-maven)
- [SWT jar for different platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134219/swt-jar-for-different-platform)
- [Create cross platform Java SWT Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706222/create-cross-platform-java-swt-application)

My requirement is to build an ant script that creates **one jar per platform**, i.e. one for Windows x86, one for Windows x64, Linux x86/x64 and so on.

Does anyone have any further insight?

Using the aforementioned methods, I was not able to produce a workable solution. It either ended with the SWT jar file not automatically being loaded or it not being included in the classpath.

If someone can come up with a working example (ideally including the complete source code), that would be grand!

Comment: Heh, nice to see someone trying to aggregate all this information in one place. Nice work!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right, so I finally came up with a solution that I successfully tested on three platforms.

The two magic components are the jar-in-jar-loader and a proper build script.

The build script with comments can be found here:

```
<project name="RandomApp" basedir="." default="clean-build">

    <property name="src.dir" value="src" />

    <!-- Define the necessary paths -->
    <property name="build.dir" value="bin_temp" />
    <property name="lib.dir" value="lib" />
    <property name="lib.deploy.dir" value="lib_swt" />
    <property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes" />
    <property name="jar.dir" value="${build.dir}/jar" />
    <property name="img.dir" value="img" />
    <property name="res.dir" value="res" />

    <!-- Define the main class -->
    <property name="main-class" value="org.baz.desktop.randomapp.gui.RandomApp" />

    <path id="base-classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar" />
    </path>

    <!-- Define the class path -->
    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar" />
        <fileset dir="${lib.deploy.dir}" includes="**/swt_win32_x64.jar" />
    </path>

    <!-- Clean previously built files -->
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
    </target>

    <!-- Compile the project -->
    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}" />
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="classpath" includeantruntime="false" />
    </target>

    <macrodef name="createclasspath">
        <attribute name="name" />
        <attribute name="swtlib" />
        <sequential>
            <pathconvert property="@{name}.classpath" pathsep=" ">
                <path refid="base-classpath" />
                <fileset dir="${lib.deploy.dir}" includes="**/swt_@{swtlib}.jar" />
                <mapper>
                    <chainedmapper>
                        <flattenmapper />
                        <globmapper from="*.jar" to="*.jar" />
                    </chainedmapper>
                </mapper>
            </pathconvert>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

    <!-- Define classpath and create the jar folder -->
    <target name="pre_jar" depends="compile">
        <!-- Linux 32bit -->
        <createclasspath name="win86" swtlib="win32_x86" />
        <!-- Linux 64bit -->
        <createclasspath name="win64" swtlib="win32_x64" />
        <!-- Windows 32bit -->
        <createclasspath name="linux86" swtlib="linux_gtk_x86" />
        <!-- Windows 64bit -->
        <createclasspath name="linux64" swtlib="linux_gtk_x64" />
        <!-- MacOS 32bit -->
        <createclasspath name="macos86" swtlib="macos_x86" />
        <!-- MacOS 64bit -->
        <createclasspath name="macos64" swtlib="macos_x64" />

        <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}" />
    </target>

    <macrodef name="createjar">
        <attribute name="swtlib" />
        <attribute name="swtclasspath" />
        <sequential>
            <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}_@{swtlib}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
                <manifest>
                    <attribute name="Main-Class" value="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader" />
                    <attribute name="Rsrc-Main-Class" value="${main-class}" />
                    <attribute name="Class-Path" value="." />
                    <attribute name="Rsrc-Class-Path" value="./ @{swtclasspath}" />
                </manifest>

                <zipgroupfileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/jar-in-jar-loader.jar" />
                <zipfileset dir="${lib.deploy.dir}" includes="**/swt_@{swtlib}.jar" />
                <zipfileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar" excludes="**/jar-in-jar-loader.jar" />
            </jar>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

    <!-- Create the jar files -->
    <target name="jar" depends="pre_jar">
        <!-- Linux 32bit -->
        <createjar swtlib="linux_gtk_x86" swtclasspath="${linux86.classpath}" />
        <!-- Linux 64bit -->
        <createjar swtlib="linux_gtk_x64" swtclasspath="${linux64.classpath}" />
        <!-- Windows 32bit -->
        <createjar swtlib="win32_x86" swtclasspath="${win86.classpath}" />
        <!-- Windows 64bit -->
        <createjar swtlib="win32_x64" swtclasspath="${win64.classpath}" />
        <!-- MacOS 32bit -->
        <createjar swtlib="macos_x86" swtclasspath="${macos86.classpath}" />
        <!-- MacOS 64bit -->
        <createjar swtlib="macos_x64" swtclasspath="${macos64.classpath}" />
    </target>

    <target name="clean-build" depends="clean,jar" />

</project>
```

What it basically does is define a base classpath *without* any SWT library.
Then it creates platform specific classpaths using the base one and adding the appropriate platform SWT library.

The `jar` task then creates a separate jar for each platform using these classpaths and the jar-in-jar-loader.

And that's it, a fully automated way of generating jars for each (supported) platform.

---

I've created an example project that people can download and test out. It's an easy starting point for a multi-platform application.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ianrbl4bn0fmsdi/SWTApplication.7z

---

**Update**:

I've managed to significantly shorten the ant script by making proper use of `macrodef` :)

Comment: Did you try to create an exe from SWT? And .dmg for OSX? without using RCP or third party paid tools ?

Comment: @AppWork Nope, I use Install4J to create those. You can get an open-source license from them though. That one's free.

Comment: @AppWork You can use Install4J for free **if** your application is a non-profit open source project and you add a link back to their website on the website of your tool. More info here: https://www.ej-technologies.com/buy/install4j/openSource

Comment: The price is too high for commercial use. Is there any other alternatives to this ? What about Nullsoft Scriptable Install System (NSIS) ? Did you try it?

Comment: launch4j and JSmooth are free to use for windows. Both have GNU General Public License.http://stackoverflow.com/a/5349215/1172155

Comment: @AppWork I've only used Install4j as all my tools are open source.