# How to get Java standalone app with eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, swt, eclipse-rcp

I want to get standalone executable app. after search and find many thing one of the most interesting for me is: [First of all please check this tutorial](https://wadeawalker.wordpress.com/2010/10/24/tutorial-creating-native-binary-executables-for-multi-platform-java-apps-with-opengl-and-eclipse-rcp/)

OK now I want to know can use that way shows on that above link for non RCP ? I mean I write a java app and now want to run it standalone I know Launch4j and other things can do it but can I do it with Eclipse too like that above tutorial ?

Comment: Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359351/build-one-jar-per-platform-for-multi-platform-swt-application) and [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_an_executable_JAR_file_for_a_stand-alone_SWT_program%3F) if a `jar` is sufficient.

Comment: That tutorial is specifically for Eclipse RCP apps - that is apps that use the Eclipse plugin architecture. Since it seems to be based on Eclipse 3.6 it is likely to be a bit out of date as well.

Comment: The best way to deploy Java desktop apps. is to install/launch the app. direct from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, *nix and OS X.