# Do I need to export my .jar differently to run on different platforms?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, portability

I have a `.jar` that I complied and exported on `Windows` via Eclipse.  It runs perfectly and now I wish to run it on a `Solaris 10` machine.

When I attempt to run it on `Solaris`, however, I get a `java.lan.UnsatisifiedLinkError` complaining it could not load a `SWT` library.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisifiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library.  Reasons:
no swt-win32-3650 in java.library.path
no swt-win32 in java.library.path
Can't load library: /var/tmp/swtlib-64/libswt-win32-3650.so
Can't load library: /var/tmp/swtlib-64/libswt-win32-3650.so
```

Why is `Java` looking for `libswt-win32` libraries?  Am I creating the `.jar` wrong?

Do I need to export the `.jar` differently when I build on `Windows` since its now intended to be run from `Solaris`?

Comment: You need a separate jar per platform containing the platform specific version of SWT. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23359351/2670892)

Answer (score 1):

SWT has a native component. I presume that you are using something from it for it to be included. You will need to have the equivalent native library installed on your Solaris system.

Have a look at the solutions here, it is on Ubuntu, but problem is similar:

[Eclipse cannot load SWT libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165693/eclipse-cannot-load-swt-libraries)

Comment: I looked at those answers previously, but none really pertain to my question.  My problem is a platform issue, whereas that question's problem is a loading issue (i.e. the solution was just to symlink where java was looking to where it should be looking).