# How to make my SWT application run on Java 32 bit and Java 64 bit machines

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, 32bit-64bit

I developed a SWT runnable jar and supposedly I'm using a 32bit and 64 bit compatible SWT .jar library.

[image]

As you can see this SWT jar has 32 and 64 in his name: `org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64`

When I execute this on my developer machine which has java jdk 64 bit installed it works perfectly, but when I execute it on a 32 bit java machine, it gives this error: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load 64-bit SWT libraries on 32-bit JVM`

Why? is not that library for both 64 and 32 bit as it's name says?

Comment: SWT libraries are different for 32 bit and 64 bit, and different for each platform. That is why there are 32 and 64 bit versions of Eclipse (which is just a very complex SWT program)

Comment: but @greg-449 then this library is for 32 or 64? what should i do?

Comment: Looks like you have to have separate version for 32 and 64 bit. Eclipse solve this problem by having two version. If they didn't know solution it means that there is no solution at all.

Comment: @talex what should i do now to make my runnable jar compatible with 32 bit java and SO?

Comment: I can't find where to download a specific 32 bits swt library :S

Comment: Look at the bottom of that page: [eclipse.org](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.9-201809060745/)

Comment: ok thank you @LuCio

Comment: As far as I know, this applies not only to SWT: 32 bit and 64 bit Java require different native libraries. Would shipping with a 32 bit JRE be an option for you? This would work for Windows 32 bit and 64 bit.

Comment: `x86_64` library is for 64 bit only and requires a 64 bit JRE. There is also an `x86` library which is 32 bit and requires a 32 bit JRE. It is usual to build separate jars for each architecture and platform. The [Eclipse Project Downloads](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/) has all the SWT builds.

Comment: @NullPointerException There are quite a few questions about 32 and 64 bit versions of SWT apps out there. [Here's one that also links to others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359351/build-one-jar-per-platform-for-multi-platform-swt-application). Mayhe that helps.